# Showing element on click method vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to display the div when the user clicks the radio input in the on click resume_radio method.

```
<form id="apply">
<p>Resume</p>
<label for="fields[resumeApplication]">
    <input type="radio" name="fields[resumeApplication]" @click="resume_radio" value="onFile" required>
    Use my resume on file
</label>

<label for="fields[resumeApplication]">
    <input type="radio" name="fields[resumeApplication]" @click="resume_radio" value="uploadFile" required>
    Upload a resume for this application
</label>

<div v-show="show_resume_upload">
    <label for="fields[resumeAttachment]">Resume upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="fields[resumeAttachment]">
</div>
</form>
```

I am just setting it to true on click for simplicity.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: 'form#apply',
    delimiter: ['{}'],
    data: {
        show_resume_upload: false,
    },
    methods: {
        resume_radio: function (event) {
            show_resume_upload: true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
show_resume_upload: true;
```

With

```
this.show_resume_upload = true;
```

Then you will update the attribute (the property inside `data`) to `true`, and VueJs will display the `div`.

Comment: haha happens to everyone @Brad . If it works for you, then you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `this` inside your method :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: 'form#apply',
  delimiter: ['{}'],
  data: {
    show_resume_upload: false,
  },
  methods: {
    resume_radio: function(event) {
     this.show_resume_upload= true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<form id="apply">
  <p>Resume</p>
  <label for="fields[resumeApplication]">
    <input type="radio" name="fields[resumeApplication]" @click="resume_radio" value="onFile" required>
    Use my resume on file
</label>

  <label for="fields[resumeApplication]">
    <input type="radio" name="fields[resumeApplication]" @click="resume_radio" value="uploadFile" required>
    Upload a resume for this application
</label>

  <div v-show="show_resume_upload">
    <label for="fields[resumeAttachment]">Resume upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="fields[resumeAttachment]">
  </div>
</form>
```